# MSWord wildcard -- a?b | a??b | a???b --> a?{1,3}b

Tags: regex, ms-word, wildcard

While using Microsoft-Word wildcard ( reg ex, regex, regexp, regular expression ),

```
 a?b   a??b   a???b     all seem to work fine.
```

How can I merge the 3 search strings into one?

```
        It's apparently not    a?{1,3}b
```

I've tried this in two completely different environments, with the same result.

For example,  for this file:  http://nfbnet.org/pipermail/blindlaw_nfbnet.org/attachments/20140121/5fffc4d6/attachment.doc

```
 Searching for    a?b     yields  0 hits. 

 Searching for    a??b     yields  33 hits. 

 Searching for    a???b     yields  106 hits.
```

But

```
 Searching for    a?{1,3}b    yields  366 hits.
```

What's the correct search string for what I want to do 
           (to get the ~139 hits)?   Thank you.

Comment: Can you give the values you're testing against? I suspect that regex is not doing what you intend.

Comment: I'm not sure Word uses regex at all. It uses "Wildcards" as you said in your title. As far as I understand it, `?` matches any single character. I don't really know much about Wildcards, but you can read more here: http://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm